# SSIS Vendor supplied flat file has no text qualifier and commas embedded in address field

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I have a collection of 4 vendor supplied csv flat files.  Using VS 2019 SSIS I am building out a data pipeline to import these files daily, into a SQL Server 2019 DB.  These files ARE NOT text qualified.  I stress this fact because almost every google search I've read this morning suggests that I merely supply a Text Qualifier in the Connection Manager.

Among the fields in each file is an Address.  Each file contains approx 250k rows and of course, a handful of the rows contains Addresses with a comma embedded in the field:

> 123 Main Street, Apt 3

This issue, of course, creates processing problems.

Given that the vendor supplied files are NOT text qualified (no double quotes surrounding text-type fields), and that a small percentage of rows embed commas within a given field, what is the Best Practice approach to solving this problem?

Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Comment: If the file isn't text qualified, and has both commas as a delimiter and in data values, it's invalid. Either the delimiter needs to be a value that isn't going to appear in the data, or the data needs to be text qualified (minimally when it contains a delimiter in its value). The fix is to get the vendor to correct the data. SSIS (or any tool) won't be able to import this natively otherwise; you'd have to use a programatical solution (such as a Script Component in your data flow).

Comment: If a row has more than the required number of commas, split it out into some sort of error file for manual processing?

Comment: Thank you @Larnu and others.  I have authored and used C# Script components in the past to clean data and today I've searched for ideas using RegEx patterns to identify this particular issue but I have not yet found a solution.  Perhaps contacting the Vendor and simply telling them the file is invalid is the Best Practice solution unless anyone here can suggest a C#/RegEx/Script Task solution.

Comment: Possibly you could try parsing the file and identify the average position for each comma, then the outlier(s) are the ones likely part of a field.

Comment: split the file into two. rows with correct number of commas and rows with too many commas. Run the good one through SSIS and manually process the too many.

Comment: However, I would start with letting the vendor know that the extract is bad. They likely can just quote wrap text fields with no problem.